# Django: QuerySet with group of same entries

Tags: python, django

My goal is to show for a specific survey the Top 10 "Entities" per question ordered from high to low by salience.
A survey has several questions. And each question has several answers. Each answer can have several entities (sometimes the same `name` (CharField), sometimes different `name`s). Entities are grouped by the `name` field per question.

I thought the following final result makes sense:

```
[
    5:  # question.pk
    [
        {
            'name': 'Leonardo Di Caprio',
            'count': 4,  # E.g. answer__pk = 1, answer__pk = 1, answer__pk = 2, answer__pk = 3. Leonardo Di Caprio was mentioned twice in answer_pk 1 and therefore has entries.
            'salience': 3.434  # Sum of all 4 entities
        },
        {
            'name': 'titanic',
            'count': 5,
            'salience': 1.12
        },
        {
            'name': 'music',
            'count': 3,
            'salience': 1.12
        }
    ],
    3:  # question.pk
    [
        {
            'name': 'Leonardo Di Caprio',
            'count': 5,
            'salience': 1.5
        },
        {
            'name': 'titanic',
            'count': 4,
            'salience': 1.12
        },
        {
            'name': 'music',
            'count': 2,
            'salience': 1.12
        }
    ],
]
```

Now I am struggling to write the right QuerySet for my desired outcome. I came to the point that I probably have to use `.values()` and `.annotate()`. But my results are quite far away from what my goal ist.

Here my models.py:

```
class Entity(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()
    salience = models.FloatField()
    sentiment_magnitude = models.FloatField()
    sentiment_score = models.FloatField()
    language = models.CharField()
    answer = models.ForeignKey(
        Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="entities"
    )

class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        "surveys.Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answers"
    )
    response = models.ForeignKey()
    answer = models.TextField()

class Question(TimeStampedModel):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(
        "surveys.Survey", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="questions"
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("Title"))
    focus = models.CharField()

class Response(TimeStampedModel):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(
        "surveys.Survey", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="responses"
    )
    order = models.ForeignKey()
    attendee = models.ForeignKey()
    total_time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    language = models.CharField()

class Survey(TimeStampedModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    event = models.ForeignKey()
    template = models.CharField()
```

Here, what I tried so far. But that seems far from what my goal ist:

```
questions = self.request.event.surveys.get_results(
    settings.SURVEY_PRE_EVENT
)

for question in questions:
    print("------")
    print(question.pk)
    
    answers = question.answers.all()
    for answer in answers:
        print(
            answer.entities.values("name")
            .annotate(count=Count("name"))
            .annotate(salience=Sum("salience"))
        )
```

Here the output:

```
------
33
<QuerySet [{'name': 'people', 'count': 1, 'salience': 1.0}]>
<QuerySet [{'name': 'income', 'count': 1, 'salience': 1.0}]>
<QuerySet [{'name': 'incomes', 'count': 2, 'salience': 1.26287645101547}]>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: I added it at the end.

Comment: Try for each question: `Entity.objects.filter(answer__question=question).values('name').annotate(count=Count('pk').annotate(total_salience=Sum('salience')`. Your current code only takes one answer at a time instead of taking all the entities linked to the question.

Comment: That seems to work! Maybe I am trying too much, but now it is an additional query for each individual question. I hoped somehow I could combine it to one query for all questions so I don't have to hit the database too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the questions in order to create a list for each question:

```
Entity.objects.filter(answer__question=question).values('name').annotate(count=Count('pk')).annotate(total_salience=Sum('salience'))
```

Or if you want to have all in one queryset, group first by question (pk):

```
Entity.objects.values('answer__question__pk', 'name').annotate(count=Count('pk')).annotate(total_salience=Sum('salience'))
```

This will produce a list, not a nested list by question, but you can later regroup this in python to nest the entities for each question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure entirely if I understood your problem correctly, but you may be looking for something like

```
Question.objects.values("answers__entities__name").annotate(
    salience=Sum("answers__entities__salience"),
    count=Count("answers"),
)
```

Disclaimers:
I haven't tested this and I may be wrong, but this is what I'd start playing around with.

Also you might find this useful: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html

Comment: It's a great article, thank you. I am currently going with the approach dirkgroten wrote from the `Entity` level. But I believe that's another solution.